# SC - ChangeServiceConfig Failed 5: on cmd

Tags: windows, service, cmd

I want to stop the service run automatically when system boots.

For specific information, I'm logged in with "administrator" account.
And opened cmd with "run as administrator"

here's the log on cmd.

```
C:\>sc config AppIDSvc start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\>sc config AppIDSvc start= demand
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

I don't understand why I can change startup type to auto but cannot to demand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can just hack the registry: (1=Sys,2=Auto,3=Manual,4=Disabled)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\WSService\Start  =  4
```

Comment: Now in Windows 10 do can not find `WSService`, but found `wscsvc`. Seems the same.

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd.exe` as administrator by right clicking on CMD and selecting `Run as Administrator`or if Windows 8 or 10, right click Start and select `Command Prompt (Admin)` then in `cmd.exe` and type:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

in the same `cmd.exe` retry:

```
sc config AppIDSvc start= demand
```

Which should return:

> [SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

If however it still gives the `access denied` error, please Restart the Computer and then run cmd.exe as Administrator and then retry:

```
sc config AppIDSvc start= demand
```